# Lambda to invoke ECS task

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

Problem statement: S3 event should trigger lambda and lambda should invoke ecs TASK.

S3 event is triggering lambda and lambda is invoking ecs task using java(handler.java)

I am using RunTaskRequest to invoke ECS TaskDefinition.

In the logs im priniting RuntaskResponse. It has all containers and arns listed and LastesStatus = pending. but when we go to ecs iam not able find the task.

any idea on how to see ecs task or figure out issue.

```
    EcsClient ecsClient = EcsClient.builder()
        .region(region)
        .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
        .build();
   
    RunTaskRequest runTaskRequest= RunTaskRequest.builder()
            .taskDefinition("tasdefinition:taskId")
            .cluster("clustername")
            .networkConfiguration("networkconfig")
            .launchType("FARGATE")
            .build();
    
    RunTaskResponse runTaskResponse = ecsClient.runTask(runTaskRequest);
    ecsClient.close();
```

Tried with above code and expecting task in aws-ecs console

Comment: Perhaps the task is erroring out quickly and stopping? Make sure you are also looking at "Stopped" tasks in ECS, those are hidden in the UI by default.